# Pass a value to an on-click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this API that I'm currently using to output a short URL or URL generator. Is there a way to pass the output to an `on-click` function.

The first script shows the API running

```
  var base_url      = window.location.origin,
      hash_bang     = "/#/sign-up?referral=",
      login         = "login",
      api_key       = "api_key";


  function get_short_url(login, api_key, func, value) {
      var value = document.getElementById('input-refcode').value;

      $.getJSON(
          "https://api-ssl.bitly.com//v3/shorten?callback=?", 
          { 
              "format": "json",
              "apiKey": api_key,
              "login": login,
              "longUrl": base_url + hash_bang + value
          },

          function(response)
          {
              func(response.data.url);
          }
      );
  }
```

---

Second is a script that shares a text via Twitter using `on-click`

```
  $('#twitter').on('click', function() {
      win = window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Get Free Rides at Electric Studio! Sign up to purchase your first timer package! After your first ride, you get 1 ride on us!', '_blank');
      win.focus();

  });
```

Is there a way to get the output from the first function `get_short_url` then bind it in a `on-click` like this for example

```
  $('#twitter').on('click', get_short_url(login, api_key, function(short_url)) {
      win = window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Get Free Rides at Electric Studio! Sign up to purchase your first timer package! After your first ride, you get 1 ride on us!' + short_url, '_blank');
      win.focus();
  });
```

I tried this solution but the browser flagged the function as a pop-up

```
  $('#twitter').on('click', function() {

     var base_url          = window.location.origin,
         hash_bang_twitter = "/%23/sign-up?referral=",
         referral_code      = document.getElementById('input-refcode').value;

       get_short_url(login, api_key, function(short_url) {
           win = window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Get Free Rides at Electric Studio! Sign up ' + short_url + ' to purchase your first timer package! After your first ride, you get 1 ride on us!' + ' https://www.electricstudio.ph/', '_blank');
           win.focus();
       });
  });
```

Comment: In **win = window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?**... close the quote at the end of **us!**

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to, you can simply wrap

```
$('#twitter').on('click', function() {

    get_short_url(login, api_key, function(short_url) {

        win = ...
        win.focus();

    });

});
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the browser will flagged this as a pop-up due to the window.open included inside the function `get_short_url`

`As a general rule, pop up blockers target windows that launch without user interaction.`

Comment: You just need to replace window.open with a lightbox, also that's not relevant to the question

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but when you mentioned lightbox. Is it like a modal?

Comment: Yes. like this https://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/ (i just snatched one at random from the web)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no pro at js, but this seems fairly simple.  I have not tested this.

```
var base_url      = window.location.origin,
    hash_bang     = "/#/sign-up?referral=",
    login         = "login",
    api_key       = "api_key";


function get_short_url() {
    var value = ('#input-refcode').val();
    var result = '';
    $.getJSON(
        "https://api-ssl.bitly.com//v3/shorten?callback=?", 
        { 
            "format": "json",
            "apiKey": api_key,
            "login": login,
            "longUrl": base_url + hash_bang + value
        },

        function(response)
        {
            result = response.data.url;
        }
    );
    return result;
};

$('#twitter').on('click', function() {
    var short_url = get_short_url(function(short_url)
    if (short_url !== '') {
        win = window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + encodeURI("Get Free Rides at Electric Studio! Sign up to purchase your first timer package! After your first ride, you get 1 ride on us! " + short_url));
        win.focus();
    }

});
```